# Change the master IP address of a kubernetes cluster

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I am running a 3-node kubernetes cluster on VirtualBox. So far, I was running the master API server on a DHCP interface which always gets a fixed address from the router based on MAC-address mappings. Instead of that, I now want to use a private network for this purpose - I have setup a host-only network for this.

What is the right way to move my kubernetes cluster to this network. Should the following work?

1. On the master:

   ```
   kubeadm reset
   kubeadm init --apiserver-advertise-address=<new-ip> --pod-network-cidr=<same-old-ip>
   ```
2. On the workers:

   ```
   kubeadm join ... new credentials ...
   ```

Is there anything else I need to ensure?

Comment: Do you try to just change the devices type in VB? May it is enough.